# Css margin-left auto makes a div leave its container

Tags: html, css

I'm learning how to make a navbar and I can't align an item properly to the left.
here's my html code

```css
.navul {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
}

.navli1 {
  margin: auto;
}

.navli2 {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.navlink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  padding: 16px 25px;
}

.navlink:hover {
  color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="navul">
    <li class="navli1">
      <a class="navlink" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navli2">
      <a class="navlink" href="#">Logout</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

here's the result, notice logout item is outside the ul container.
[image: header]

Comment: How about `display: block` for the `li`

Comment: No. to the `.navLink`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove height of ".navul" and add "display: block" to ".navlink"

```css
.navul {
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
}
.navli1 {
    margin: auto;
}
.navli2 {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.navlink{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    padding: 16px 25px;
    display: block;
}
.navlink:hover {
    color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <ul class="navul">
            <li class="navli1">
                <a class="navlink" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navli2">
                <a class="navlink" href="#">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: would you mind explaining how does inline block fix the problem, I added it and it worked but I don't know the logic behind it

Comment: display: inline-block allows to set a width and height on the element.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.navul {
        display: flex;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
    }

    .navli1 {
        margin: auto;
    }

    .navli2 {
        margin: auto 0px auto auto;
    }

    .navlink {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        padding: 16px 25px;
    }

    .navlink:hover {
        color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    }

    ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <ul class="navul">
            <li class="navli1">
                <a class="navlink" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navli2">
                <a class="navlink" href="#">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</body>
```

In the navli1 you are telling CSS to have margin auto on top, right, bottom and  left, whereas in navli2 you were only telling the margin left. This caused the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `flex` completely. Use styles such as `justify-content` and `flex-direction` to complete the design.

```css
.navul {
    display: flex;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: spacearound;
}
.navli1 {
    margin: auto;
}
.navli2 {
    margin: auto;
}

.navlink{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    padding: 16px 25px;
}
.navlink:hover {
    color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <ul class="navul">
            <li class="navli1">
                <a class="navlink" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navli2">
                <a class="navlink" href="#">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
```